# How to do "decode 'unicode-escape'" only on \xhh characters in a string in Perl?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, decoding, unicode-escapes

I have a file with the following content with some characters are UTF-8 hex encoded in the string literal:

```
<root>
<element type=\"1\">\"Hello W\xC3\x96rld\"</element>
</root>
```

I want to read the file and decode the UTF-8 hex encoded characters in the file to the actual unicode characters they represent and then write to a new file.  Given the above content, the new file should look like the following when you open it in a text editor with UTF-8 encoding:

```
<root>
<element type=\"1\">\"Hello WÖrld\"</element>
</root>
```

Notice the double quotes are still escaped and the UTF-8 hex encoded `\xC3\x96` has now become Ö (U+00D6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS).

I have got code that is partially working, as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Encode::Escape;

while (<>)
{
    # STDOUT is redirected to a new file.
    print decode 'unicode-escape', $_;
}
```

The problem however, all the other escape sequences such as `\"` are being decoded as well by `decode 'unicode-escape', $_`.  So in the end, I get the following:

```
<root>
<element type="1">"Hello WÖrld"</element>
</root>
```

I have tried reading the file in UTF-8 encoding and/or using `Unicode::Escape::unescape` such as

```
open(my $UNICODESFILE, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", shift(@ARGV));
Unicode::Escape::unescape($line);
```

but neither of them decode the `\xhh` escape sequences.

Basically all I want is the behavior of `decode 'unicode-escape', $_`, but that it should only decode on `\xhh` escape sequences and ignore other escape sequences.

Is this possible?  Is using `decode 'unicode-escape', $_` appropriate for this case?  Any other way?  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I appreciate what you are trying to do, but I wonder if this is not a X/Y problem and the whether you're trying to do things this way because of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find groups of \xNN characters and process them, I guess:

```
s{((?:\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+)}{decode 'unicode-escape', $1}ge
```

Comment: Nor a 1-byte encoding, which I think is what that was actually matching. I've updated it. Bad me for not testing first.